# Various definitions of weak solutions and continuity property

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

For example, consider the transport equation
$$
\partial_tu+b\cdot\partial_xu=0, u(0,x)=u_0(x),
$$
where $t\ge0,x\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $b\in W^{1,1}_{\rm{loc}}([0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^3)$.

It seems that the definitions of weak solutions depend on the forms of test function spaces. I wonder the   difference and relationship of the following cases. More precisely, I want to figure it out the   difference of the continuity at $t=0$ of them.

1. The space of test functions is defined as $C_c^{\infty}([0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^3)$.
2. The space of test functions is defined as $C_c^{\infty}((0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^3)$and the weak solutions are equipped with the continuity property in a sense at $t=0$, e.g., weakly in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Comment: Maybe you could be a bit more precise in what exactly you are interested in, and what your current insights are. For instance, have you looked at, for example, Section 4 in Ambrosio's "Transport equation and Cauchy problem for BV vector fields", and Section 2.3 in DeLellis' "Ordinary differential equations with rough coefficients and the renormalization theorem of Ambrosio" (Seminaire Bourbaki) for comparison?